# apollo client query with params - Vue

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo-client

Apollo-client's query:

```
apolloClient
  .query({
    query: authQuery,
    variables: {
      login: payload.login,
      password: payload.password,
    },
  })
  .then((res) => console.log(res)
```

Contents of authQuery (it's inside a file.gql):

```
query auth {
  data
}
```

i always get the following response:

```
{
  data: null
  loading: false
  networkStatus: 7
  stale: true
}
```

Though in graphiQL i am getting correct response:

Query in a GraphiQL

```
{
  auth(login:"root@admin", password:"1234")
}
```

And response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "auth": "eyJhbGciOi8"
  }
}
```

I suspect my file.gql is the culprit? Or variables inside query not being read?

Comment: Your query doesnt include any variables?

Comment: You can see `variables` inside my .query

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap my query this way:

```
query Auth($login: String!, $password: String!) {
  auth (login: $login, password: $password)
}
```

When you're using params with your Query, you always have to wrap it this way.